# Django get_initial not working

Tags: django-forms, django-views

Django get_initial is not populating product field in the form. I am expecting a drop down, with the queryset results as defined in the get_initial overridden function.

```
class PurchaseRequestDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseRequestDetail
        fields = ["product", "variations", "quantity", "fulfilled", "vat", "discount", "surcharges", "active"]
        exclude = ("purchase_request", )


class PurchaseRequestDetailCreateView(CreateView):
    model = PurchaseRequestDetail
    form_class = PurchaseRequestDetailForm
    template_name = "inventory/purchaserequestdetail_form.html"

    def get_pr_obj(self):
        pr_id = self.request.session["pr_id"]
        return PurchaseRequest.objects.get(id=pr_id)

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(PurchaseRequestDetailCreateView, self).get_initial()
        try:
            pr_obj = self.get_pr_obj()
            initial["product"] = pr_obj.vendor.vendors_products.all()
        except KeyError:
            pass
        self.form_class(initial)
        return initial
```

template:

```
<td>{{ form.product|css_class:"form-control" }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to set a `ModelChoiceField` queryset is to set the field attribute in the form `init()`;

```
class PurchaseRequestDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        # Get initial data passed from the view
        self.product = None
        if 'product' in kwargs['initial']:
            self.product = kwargs['initial'].pop('product')

        super(PurchaseRequestDetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['product'].queryset = self.product

    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseRequestDetail
        fields = ["product", "variations", "quantity", "fulfilled", "vat", "discount", "surcharges", "active"]
        exclude = ("purchase_request", )
```

You should hook in to `get_form_kwargs` from `ModelFormMixin` to pass your data to the form.

```
class PurchaseRequestDetailCreateView(CreateView):
    model = PurchaseRequestDetail
    form_class = PurchaseRequestDetailForm
    template_name = "inventory/purchaserequestdetail_form.html"

    def get_pr_obj(self):
        pr_id = self.request.session["pr_id"]
        return PurchaseRequest.objects.get(id=pr_id)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """
        Returns the keyword arguments for instantiating the form.
        """
        kwargs = super(PurchaseRequestDetailCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(
            {'initial': 
                {'product': pr_obj.vendor.vendors_products.all()}
            }
        )
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Isn't this redundant?

Comment: if "product" in kwargs["initial"] throws a KeyError

Comment: @tilaprimera I've just looked at `CreateView` in more detail & it doesn't have a `get_initial` method. That probably just belongs to `UpdateView`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: get_initial is in FormMixin class, which is being inherited by CreateView via multiple parents like BaseCreateView, ModelFormMixin..

Comment: @tilaprimera Ah right, I might not of gone high enough up the tree, I was looking at `ModelFormMixin`. Something to put in your bookmarks though is this; http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/